# Creating an interface from a huge class using resharper

Tags: interface, resharper, refactoring

I have a very big class with lots of methods, is it possible to build an interface from this class using Resharper?

Comment: Resharper will also help you break this very big class with lots of methods into something more maintainable.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

My shortcut is Ctrl + Shift + R to bring up the refactoring options. Doing this on the class name allows you to" Extract Interface..."

Optionally, you can choose from the menu > ReSharper > Refactor > Extract Interface...

Answer (score 3):

Uh, maybe I'm missing something here (I've never used resharper) but you can extract an interface from a class using the standard VS IDE refactoring tools (at least you can in 2008). Right click the class, select 'Refactor' and then 'Extract Interface'. This will bring up a dialog box where you can select which properties to include.