# Generate a class from an Interface

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Suppose I have a new interface:

```
public interface IClientRepository 
{
    void Add(Customer customer);
    void Remove(Customer customer);
    Customer Get(long id);
}
```

Now I'd like to do the following:

- Create a new class with a good default name (e.g. "`ClientRepository`");
- Have that class in a file as a sibling of the interface code file.

I think I've seen instructors of Pluralsight videos do this on numerous occasions, but I can't seem to find out what keyboard shortcuts to use for this.

What have I tried? Well:

- [Google Fu](https://www.google.nl/search?q=ReSharper%20generate%20class%20from%20interface) mostly provides a way to do the opposite (extract interface), e.g. [posts like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1268424/419956).
- Read through the [Refactorings](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Index.html) docs for ReSharper as well as those for [Code Generation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Index.html).
- Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> on the interface declaration, but none of the options seems to be what I need.

What am I missing here? How do you generate a class from an interface?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Put the cursor on the interface type name, for instance here:

   ```
    public interface |IClientRepository
   ```

   Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and select *Create Derived Type*.  This creates a class called `ClientRepository` in the same file as `IClientRepository`.
2. Now put your cursor on the class type name of `ClientRepository`, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and select *Move to another file*.  It will default to a file name that matches the type name and puts it in the same directory as the file it was moved from.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use ReSharper, but I think you have to declare your class as derived from the interface, and then use ReSharper to implement the interface members, as explained [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Implementing_Overriding_Methods.html).

You can probably create the new class in the same file as the interface, and then use some "move" refactoring to create the corresponding files.

Answer (score 0):

I think Resharper does not have this possibility. However you can do it semi-manually.
Type the following in the same file where

```
public class ClientRepository : IClientRepository {}
```

Then use `implement members` command.

Then use `refactor -> move to another file` command on the class